# Angular 2 using templateUrl styleUrl locations upstream from index.html

Tags: angular

As I understand, all templateUrl and styleUrl paths in Angular 2 components are resolved from `index.html`.

I however want to separate my development and running folders and hence have my .html files with my .ts modules, routers, components, etc. in a `dev` folder. And have compiled the .js to a sibling `app` folder where angular should be launched from.

The directory structure looks like so:

```
top directory
|
*-- app (compiled .js here, index.html here)
|
*-- dev (.ts here, .component.html files here)
```

the issue is I can't access .component.html files in the `dev` folder while `index.html` sits in the app folder. I have tried absolute pathing from the app folder to go up and into the sibling folder, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app/../dev/path/path.component.html'
    ...
)}
```

The error in the above case is 404 not found on the .html file from `localhost:3000/dev/path/path.component.html`

Copying the .component.html structure and files into /app works but is messy.

Is it possible to set the templateUrl (styleUrl) locations upstream to a parent or sibling from where `index.html` is?

Answer (score 1):

Didn't resolve this through pathing. The solution was either to compile the htmls directly into the Angular2 components or to copy the htmls into the `app` folder